# Navigation bars with thumbnails in Windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, navigation, appbar

[Navigation Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761500.aspx) does mention that we can include thumbnails in the Navigation bar(top app bar) for buttons. I have searched for examples but found none. 
I have created a basic top app bar.

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appbar with thumbnail doesn't need any special code. Check the below given code. You can put anything within `Grid`.

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar Height="180" Background="Tan">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid Height="160" Width="200" Background="Red" Margin="10"/>
            <Grid Height="160" Width="200" Background="Green" Margin="10"/>
            <Grid Height="160" Width="200" Background="Yellow" Margin="10"/>
            <Grid Height="160" Width="200" Background="Blue" Margin="10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```